# Where to call axios.interceptors.request.use in a Vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, vuex

I am trying to use [`Amazon Cognito Vuex Module`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-vuex-module) in my Vue.js app and make all `axios` requests pass the credentials automatically with the following code:

```
// Add authentication token to each request
axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
    const response = await store.dispatch('getUserSession');
if (response && response.accessToken && response.accessToken.jwtToken) {
    config.headers.AccessToken = response.accessToken.jwtToken;
}
    return config;
});
```

As far as I see, it is a common code that should be executed for all the components probably, but it is not clear where to add it. Probably to `App.vue` or to `index.js`? In `App.vue` I have:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

    Vue.use(Vuetify);
    Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
```

in `index.js`:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use it as in the code below but before doing that you have to install these modules :

```
 npm i --save axios vue-axios vuex
```

code :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import store from './index'
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

export default new Vue({
 store,
  mounted(){
    axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
     const response = await store.dispatch('getUserSession');
       if (response && response.accessToken && response.accessToken.jwtToken) {
          config.headers.AccessToken = response.accessToken.jwtToken;
       }
    return config;
     });
  }
  }).$mount('#app');
```

here you call  `store` instead of `$store` because the variable is declared above (`import store from './index'`) but in child components you must use `this.$store` and the `this` keyword refers to the `Vue` instance

Answer (score 2):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import store from './index'
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

export default new Vue({
 store,
  created(){
    axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
     const response = await store.dispatch('getUserSession');
       if (response && response.accessToken && response.accessToken.jwtToken) {
          config.headers.AccessToken = response.accessToken.jwtToken;
       }
    return config;
     });
  }
  }).$mount('#app');
```

should use created